# Kafka stream load to data frame display data azure data bricks

Tags: azure, apache-kafka-streams, databricks, azure-databricks, pyspark

We have on-premise kafka streaming data to Azure data bricks setup; We used below query to connect to on-premise host

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:10.10.10.120:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "SIP.SIP.MENT") \
  .option("minPartitions", "10")  \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load()
```

Then next we used
display(df)

we never get any results to be displayed, consumer is working fine on the server.

Full Error

```html
    [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-6c634c0d-01de-4840-a7b9-414326972173-2063739220-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-6c634c0d-01de-4840-a7b9-414326972173-2063739220-driver-0] Discovered group coordinator xyz.xyz.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
20/10/28 01:26:20 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-6c634c0d-01de-4840-a7b9-414326972173-2063739220-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-6c634c0d-01de-4840-a7b9-414326972173-2063739220-driver-0] Error connecting to node xyz.xyz.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: xyz.xyz.com: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the host1 part:

```
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "10.10.10.120:9092")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure that you are using the correct syntax for the `kafka.bootstrap.servers`.

[image]

**Syntax:**  `("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "Host_IP_address:Port")` .

Modify your code accordingly.

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "10.10.10.120:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "SIP.SIP.MENT") \
  .option("minPartitions", "10")  \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load()
```

Comment: got Error connecting to node xyz.xyz.com:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: xyz.xyz.com
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
 at kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:104)